# Website responsibility on mobile not working, preview from Brackets doesn't look like the actual online website

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

So I decided to do my portfolio website on my own, which turned out to work pretty ok so far. The only problem is that I can't seem to make it display properly on mobile view. That's even though I've made all the pertinent changes on the css with "@media screen"

Can somebody take a look and tell me why it's doing what it's doing?

To see the problem, go to https://er-sc.com/HTML/image_making.html
on mobile view

In the proper way the image shouldn't cover the "about" button.

Also if you notice anything I could correct to make the website better, let me know.

Looking forward to the community's feedback and suggestions.
Best,
Ellie

Here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>ERSC Image Making</title>
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
    <link href="../CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body id="bigwrapper">
    <div class="topleft">
      <a class="logoButton" href="https://www.er-sc.com/">E</a>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomleft">
      <a class="logoButton" href="https://www.er-sc.com/">S</a>
      </div>
      <div class="topright">
          <a class="logoButton" href="https://www.er-sc.com/">R</a>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomright">
          <a class="logoButton" href="https://www.er-sc.com/">C</a>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomcenterLinks">
          <a href="/HTML/about.html">ABOUT</a>
      </div>
      <div class="projectWrapper">
          <div class="oneProject">
              <div class="text">Happy Dancer, 2022</div>
              <img src="/images/image-making/22-happy-dancer_k.jpg" alt="figure jumping">
          </div>
          <div class="oneProject">
              <div class="text">Relief, 2022</div>
              <img src="/images/image-making/22-0127_1__0020_Ebene-21-Wiederhergestellt_k.jpg" alt="3D extrusion of a scribble with plaster texture">
          </div>
          <div class="oneProject">
              <div class="text">Didi, 2021</div>
              <img src="/images/image-making/21-1210didi_k.jpg">    
          </div>
          <div class="oneProject">
              <div class="text">Dancing Flowers pt I, 2021</div>
              <img src="/images/image-making/21-IG1_k.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="oneProject">
              <div class="text">Dancing Flowers pt II, 2021</div>
              <img src="/images/image-making/21-IG2_k.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="oneProject">
              <div class="text">Sad Clown, 2021</div>
              <img src="/images/image-making/21-200126_3D_1_k.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="oneProject">
              <div class="text">Alpine Anime (fictitious festival poster for Livia Rita), 2020</div>
              <img src="/images/image-making/20-AlpineAnime_k.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="oneProject">
              <div class="text">Europa Endlos, 2019</div>
              <img src="/images/image-making/19-europaendlos-scan_k.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="oneProject">
              <div class="text">Ascension, 2018</div>
              <img src="/images/image-making/18-plakat_klein_ersc_k.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="oneProject">
              <div class="text">Seoul Impressions 1/4, 2018</div>
              <img src="/images/image-making/18-1_k.jpg">            
          </div>
          <div class="oneProject">
              <div class="text">Seoul Impressions 2/4, 2018</div>
              <img src="/images/image-making/18-7_k.jpg">              
          </div>
          <div class="oneProject">
              <div class="text">Seoul Impressions 3/4, 2018</div>
              <img src="/images/image-making/18-9_k.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="oneProject">
              <div class="text">Seoul Impressions 4/4, 2018</div>
              <img src="/images/image-making/18-10_k.jpg">
          </div>
          
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's my CSS

```
html, 

#index {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, hsla(295, 79%, 24%, 1) 0%, hsla(71, 66%, 78%, 1) 40%, hsla(318, 76%, 81%, 1) 74%, hsla(202, 27%, 45%, 1) 100%);); 

    color: #551A8B; 
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#bigwrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, hsla(295, 79%, 24%, 1) 0%, hsla(71, 66%, 78%, 1) 40%, hsla(318, 76%, 81%, 1) 74%, hsla(202, 27%, 45%, 1) 100%);); 

    color: #551A8B; 
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: top !important;
    align-items: top !important;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'FT88-Italic';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('/fonts/FT88-Italic') format('woff2');
}

p {
    font-family: 'FT88-Italic', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'FT88-Italic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.socials{
    font-size: 2vw;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #551A8B;
    font-family: sans-serif;

}

mark {
    background-color: rgba(85, 26, 139, 1);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0.3em;

}

#wrapper {
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0em;
    
}



.extraBG {
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50vw;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    right: 0%;
    top:0%
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.topleft{
    position: fixed;
    top: 3%;
    left: 3%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.bottomleft{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 3%;
    left: 3%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.topright{
    position: fixed;
    top: 3%;
    right: 3%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.bottomright{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 3%;
    right: 3%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.bottomcenterLinks{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    font-family: "FT88-Italic", sans-serif;
    font-size: 3vh;
    color: floralwhite;
}

.bottomcenterLinks a {
    color: floralwhite;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0.25em #551A8B;
}

.bottomcenterLinks a:hover {
    color: floralwhite;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0.15em floralwhite;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}

.bottomcenterLinks a:active {
    color: floralwhite;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0.15em floralwhite;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}

.bottomSmall{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.logoButton {
    background-color: floralwhite;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 8vh;
    height: 8vh;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 3vh;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: inset 6px -6px 8px 1px rgba(224, 211, 185, 0.8), inset -16px 14px 10px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    transition: 0.25s ease;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 999;
    filter: blur(0.05em);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0.05em);
}

.logoButton:hover, .logoButton:active{
    box-shadow: inset 6px -6px 0.8em 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), inset -16px 18px 0.8em 0.05em rgba(224, 211, 185, 0.8);
    filter: blur(0em);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0em);
}

.centeredBox{
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 5em;
    background: floralwhite;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0.6em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: auto;
    height: 90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap : nowrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items : stretch;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content : space-between;

   /* box-shadow: inset 6px -6px 0.5em 1px rgba(224, 211, 185, 0.5), inset -16px 14px 10px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    transition: 0.25s ease; 
    */
}

.centeredBox small{
    text-align: center;
    align-content : flex-end;
}

.part1, .part2, .part3, .part4, .part5{
    border-radius: 100em;
    background: floralwhite;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 6px -6px 0.5em 1px rgba(224, 211, 185, 0.5), inset -16px 14px 10px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    transition: 0.25s ease;
    vertical-align: middle;
    filter: blur(0.1em);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0.1em);
}

.part1:hover, .part2:hover, .part3:hover, .part4:hover, .part5:hover, .part5:active {
    
    box-shadow: inset -21px 26px 50px -51px #FFFAF0, inset 10px -13px 50px -31px #FFFAF0, inset 34px -36px 50px 35px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), inset -31px 37px 50px 32px rgba(224, 211, 185, 0.25);
    filter: blur(0em);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0em);
    
}


/*
.centeredBox, .slideshowBox{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
*/
.centeredBox p {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
    height:20px;
    top: 5%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.part1 {
    width:50%;
    height: 30%;
    float: left;
}

.part1 p{
    position: relative;
    height:20px;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.part2 {
    width:50%;
    height: 30%;
    float: left;
}

.part2 p{
    position: relative;
    height:20px;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.part3 {
    width:50%;
    height: 30%;
    float: left;
}

.part3 p{
    position: relative;
    height:20px;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.part4 {
    width:50%;
    height: 30%;
    float: left;
}

.part4 p{
    position: relative;
    height:20px;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.part5 {
    width:65%;
    height: 33%;
    margin: auto;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.part5 p {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 6vw;
    margin: auto;
  /*  transform: translateY(-50%); */
}

.selected{
    color: #FFFAF0;
    filter: blur(0.05em);
}

.slideshowBox{
    border-radius: 4em;
    background: floralwhite;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    filter: drop-shadow(10px,10px,orange);
}

.slideshow-container{
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    padding-top: 0em;
    padding-bottom: 0em;
    border-radius: 4em;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;  
}
.projectWrapper {
    z-index: 10;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 5em;
    /*overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;*/
    padding-bottom: 7.5em; 
}

.oneProject {
    padding-bottom: 7.5em;
    /*scroll-snap-align: start;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;*/
}

img {
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    border-radius: 1em;
    max-height: 75vh;
    max-width: 75vw;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.imgSmall {
    max-height: 70vh;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev {
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 0em;
    width: 40%;
    padding-top: 17em;
    padding-bottom: 17em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 1.2em;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    right: 0em;
    width: 40%;
    padding-top: 17em;
    padding-bottom: 17em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 1.2em;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    user-select: none;
  
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    font-family: sans-serif;

}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .6} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    h1 {
    font-size: 4vw;
    }
    .socials {
        font-size: 3vw;
    }
    
    .bottomcenterLinks {
        font-size: 3vh;
    }
    .selected {
        font-size: 3vh;
    }
    
    .centeredBox small{
    font-size: 3vw;    
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .oneProject {
        margin-bottom: 40%;
    }
    .projectWrapper {
        margin-top: 30%;
    }
    .logoButton {
        filter: blur(0.03em);
        -webkit-filter: blur(0.03em);
    }
    .part5 {
        filter: blur(0.06em);
        -webkit-filter: blur(0.06em);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Pls add your code so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, I think that it's because you added z-index directly to the about link tag in your css. Try adding z-index to the link wrapper div, in this case "bottomcenterLinks".

```
.bottomcenterLinks{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    font-family: "FT88-Italic", sans-serif;
    font-size: 3vh;
    color: floralwhite;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

**now, a feedback for your website design:**

it's a pretty innovative design but thinking in user experience i would change the  buttons because when we first get into the page we can't understand the purpose of the buttons because they don't have proper names, I mean, self explanatory names. i understand that you wanted to use your name first letters but for the purpose of a portfolio or even another type of website you're building, I think is better building something that will literaly guide the user through the website. think about it!

also, this about link that you're trying to make appear, i think it would be better if you style it like the buttons with your name first letters, it would make it stand out better. oh and i think that instead of having only ***about***, you could have ***about me*** written there because when I first saw it I couldn't understand what that about link is supposed to be I mean, is about what, the projects, you, the page?

last but not less important, the blur in your buttons in a user perspective seems like the content is not in a good quality. i don't understand what you wanted it to look like but if you like it that way, no need to change, except if you want to prioritize user exp! besides this, i wouldn't fix anything else, i really enjoyed your design, is cute, innovative, simple, you're doing well!

sry about the big comment tho, but i hope you understand my feedback!